# Line protocol point generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this little tool for something I was trying to accomplish at work. It works as intended but a personal goal of mine is to improve my code design so it's more simple, readable, and contributable.

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/samhld/lp_generate) but a snippet of relevant code is at bottom of the question.

The main thing I'm seeking help on is the passing of arguments through the whole stack. In the below code abstraction (or the repo, if you checked that out), you'll notice that function definitions and calling the functions involve passing a ton of arguments repeatedly. I'd prefer to make that cleaner if possible. I've looked into *args and **kwargs but not sure that's necessarily a best practice here. I'm also thinking about using Dataclasses or NamedTuples, perhaps. BTW, I'm leaning toward NamedTuples because they can be iterated on. I guess Dataclasses can't so that might be too inflexible for me? I.e., if I created a NamedTuple called args out of the args from parse_args(), I would want to pass it to functions as *args, right? Only doable with a NamedTuple?

Update: Added full code below:

```
    
import time
import argparse
import random
import string
import datetime

letters = string.ascii_lowercase

def _gen_string(num):
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(num))
    return(result_str)

def _gen_int(num):
    lower_bound = 10 ** (num - 1)
    upper_bound = 10 ** num - 1
    return(random.randint(lower_bound,upper_bound))

def gen_tag(tag_key_size, tag_value_size, key=''):
    # return string Tag key-value pair
    if key:
        held_key = 'tag_' + key
        held_key = held_key[:-4]
        val = _gen_string(tag_value_size)
        pair = f",{held_key}={val}"
    else:
        key = 'tag_' + _gen_string((tag_key_size-4))
        val = _gen_string(tag_value_size)
        pair = f",{key}={val}"

    return(pair)

def gen_str_field(field_key_size, field_value_size, key=''):
    # return string Tag key-value pair
    if key:
        held_key = 'str_' + key
        held_key = held_key[:-4]
        val = _gen_string(field_key_size)
        pair = f',{held_key}="{val}"'
    else:
        key = 'str_' + _gen_string(field_key_size-4)
        val = _gen_string(field_value_size)
        pair = f',{key}="{val}"'

    return(pair)

def gen_int_field(field_key_size, int_value_size, key=''):
    # return int Field key-value pair
    if key:
        held_key = 'int_' + key
        held_key = held_key[:-4]
        val = _gen_int(int_value_size)
        pair = f",{held_key}={val}"
    else:
        key = 'int_' + _gen_string(field_key_size-4)
        val = _gen_int(int_value_size)
        pair = f",{key}={val}i"
    return(pair)

def gen_float_field(field_key_size, float_value_size, key=''):
    # return float Field key-value pair
    if key:
        held_key = 'fl_' + key
        held_key = held_key[:-3]
        val = _gen_int(float_value_size)
        pair = f",{held_key}={val}"
    else:
        key = 'fl_' + _gen_string(field_key_size-3)
        val = round(random.uniform(10,99), float_value_size-2)
        pair = f",{key}={val}"
    return(pair)

def gen_ts(precision = 's'):
    now  = datetime.datetime.now()
    ts = now.timestamp()
    if precision == ('s' or 'S'):
        ts = round(ts)
        return(ts*1000000000)
    elif precision == ('ms' or 'MS'):
        ts = round(ts*1000)
        return(ts*1000000)
    elif precision == ('us' or 'US'):
        ts = round(ts*1000000)
        return(ts*1000)
    elif precision == ('ns' or 'NS'):
        ts = round(ts*1000000000)
        return(ts)
    else:
        print("Warn: gen_ts() only takes `s`, `ms`, `us`, or `ns` as inputs")
        return ts

# Return set of Tag key-value pairs with trailing space
def gen_tagset(num_tags, tag_key_size, tag_value_size, tag_keys):
    if tag_keys:
        tagset = ''.join(gen_tag(tag_key_size,tag_value_size, key=i) for i in tag_keys) + ' ' 
    else:
        tagset = ''.join(gen_tag(tag_key_size,tag_value_size) for i in range(num_tags)) + ' '
    
    return(tagset[1:]) # remove leading comma

# Following 3 functions are helper functions for `gen_fieldset()`
def _gen_int_fieldset(int_fields, field_key_size, int_value_size, int_field_keys):
    if int_field_keys:
        int_fieldset = ''.join(gen_int_field(field_key_size,int_value_size, key=i) for i in int_field_keys)       
    else:
        int_fieldset = ''.join(gen_int_field(field_key_size,int_value_size) for i in range(int_fields))

    return(int_fieldset[1:])

def _gen_float_fieldset(float_fields, field_key_size, float_value_size, float_field_keys):
    if float_field_keys:
        float_fieldset = ''.join(gen_float_field(field_key_size,float_value_size, key=i) for i in float_field_keys) 
    else:
        float_fieldset = ''.join(gen_float_field(field_key_size,float_value_size) for i in range(float_fields))
    
    return(float_fieldset[1:])

def _gen_str_fieldset(str_fields, field_key_size, str_value_size, str_field_keys):
    if str_field_keys:
        str_fieldset = ''.join(gen_str_field(field_key_size,str_value_size, key=i) for i in str_field_keys)
    else:
        str_fieldset = ''.join(gen_str_field(field_key_size,str_value_size) for i in range(str_fields))
    return(str_fieldset[1:])

# Use fieldset helper functions to generate a full fieldset
def gen_fieldset(int_fields, 
                float_fields, 
                str_fields, 
                field_key_size,
                int_value_size,
                float_value_size,
                str_value_size,
                int_field_keys,
                float_field_keys,
                str_field_keys):
    int_fieldset = _gen_int_fieldset(int_fields, field_key_size, int_value_size, int_field_keys)
    float_fieldset = _gen_float_fieldset(float_fields, field_key_size, float_value_size, float_field_keys)
    str_fieldset = _gen_str_fieldset(str_fields, field_key_size, str_value_size, str_field_keys)

    fieldset = ''
    if int_fieldset:
        fieldset += f"{int_fieldset},"
    if float_fieldset:
        fieldset += f"{float_fieldset},"
    if str_fieldset:
        fieldset += f"{str_fieldset},"

    return(fieldset[:-1]+' ') # remove leading and trailing comma

def gen_line(measurement,
                num_tags,
                int_fields,
                float_fields,
                str_fields,
                tag_key_size,
                tag_value_size,
                field_key_size,
                int_value_size,
                float_value_size,
                str_value_size,
                precision,
                tag_keys,
                int_field_keys,
                float_field_keys,
                str_field_keys):


    tagset = gen_tagset(num_tags, tag_key_size, tag_value_size, tag_keys)
    fieldset = gen_fieldset(int_fields, float_fields, str_fields, field_key_size, int_value_size, float_value_size, str_value_size, int_field_keys, float_field_keys, str_field_keys)
    timestamp = gen_ts(precision)
    line = f"{measurement},{tagset}{fieldset}{timestamp}"

    return(line)

def gen_batch(measurement, 
                batch_size,
                num_tags,
                int_fields,
                float_fields,
                str_fields,
                tag_key_size,
                tag_value_size,
                field_key_size,
                int_value_size,
                float_value_size,
                str_value_size,
                precision,
                keep_keys_batch,
                keep_keys_session,
                tag_keys,
                int_field_keys,
                float_field_keys,
                str_field_keys):

    # Generate keys at batch level if `hold_keys` is True. 
    # This will keep Tag keys constant per line, reducing Series creation at database level.
    if keep_keys_session:
        tag_keys         = tag_keys
        int_field_keys   = int_field_keys
        float_field_keys = float_field_keys
        str_field_keys   = str_field_keys
    elif keep_keys_batch:
        tag_keys         = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(num_tags)]
        int_field_keys   = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(int_fields)]
        float_field_keys = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(float_fields)]
        str_field_keys   = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(str_fields)]
    else:
        tag_keys         = []
        int_field_keys   = []
        float_field_keys = []
        str_field_keys   = []
        
    batch = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        line = gen_line(measurement, 
                            num_tags,
                            int_fields,
                            float_fields,
                            str_fields,
                            tag_key_size,
                            tag_value_size,
                            field_key_size,
                            int_value_size,
                            float_value_size,
                            str_value_size,
                            precision,
                            tag_keys,
                            int_field_keys,
                            float_field_keys,
                            str_field_keys)
        batch.append(line)

    return(batch)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Generate a batch of Line Protocol points of a specified shape")
    parser.add_argument('measurement', type=str, default='cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--num_tags', type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument('--int_fields', type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument('--float_fields', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--str_fields', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--tag_key_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--tag_value_size', type=int, default=10)  
    parser.add_argument('--field_key_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--int_value_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--float_value_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--str_value_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--precision', type=str, choices = ['s','S','ms','MS','us','US','ns','NS'], default='s')
    parser.add_argument('--keep_keys_batch', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--keep_keys_session', action='store_true', help="")


    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.keep_keys_session:
        tag_keys         = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.num_tags)]
        int_field_keys   = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.int_fields)]
        float_field_keys = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.float_fields)]
        str_field_keys   = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.str_fields)]
        args.keep_keys_batch  = True
    else:
        tag_keys = []
        int_field_keys = []
        float_field_keys = []
        str_field_keys = []

    batch = gen_batch(args.measurement, 
                args.batch_size,
                args.num_tags,
                args.int_fields,
                args.float_fields,
                args.str_fields,
                args.tag_key_size,
                args.tag_value_size,
                args.field_key_size,
                args.int_value_size,
                args.float_value_size,
                args.str_value_size,
                args.precision,
                args.keep_keys_batch,
                args.keep_keys_session,
                tag_keys,
                int_field_keys,
                float_field_keys,
                str_field_keys)

    for line in batch:
        print(line)
```

The entire set of arguments is generated from flags at the command line so I generate a Namespace of these args.  I imagine there's a much cleaner way to pass all these arguments through the stack of this application?

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help out here!

Comment: @Reinderien Ok -- I added the full code.  It's laid out differently than this in the repo but I moved all the code into a single place for this.

Comment: Yep will fix.  Was deleting calls the module that I flattened out of this.

Comment: @Reinderien errors should be fixed.  Sorry about that.  turning that into one file led to some hiccups.

Comment: No worries; it's basically a good question now 

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that kwargs isn't a good idea. It would simplify the code quite a bit, and it is a pretty common way of doing this. You could do a data class, but it's trivial to copy the argparse args into a dictionary using the vars() function.

I didn't redo all of your code, but you can get the idea from this snippet:

```
import argparse

def gen_batch(**kwargs):

    # Generate keys at batch level if `hold_keys` is True. 
    # This will keep Tag keys constant per line, reducing Series creation at database level.

    # Simplified...
    # if keep_keys_session:
        # tag_keys         = tag_keys
        # int_field_keys   = int_field_keys
        # float_field_keys = float_field_keys
        # str_field_keys   = str_field_keys
    if not keep_keys_session and keep_keys_batch:
        tag_key_size = kwargs.get('tag_key_size')
        kwargs['tag_keys']         = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(kwargs.get('num_tags'))]
        kwargs['int_field_keys']   = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(kwargs.get('int_fields'))]
        kwargs['float_field_keys'] = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(kwargs.get('float_fields'))]
        kwargs['str_field_keys']   = [_gen_string(tag_key_size) for i in range(kwargs.get('str_fields'))]
    elif not keep_keys_session:
        kwargs['tag_keys']         = []
        kwargs['int_field_keys']   = []
        kwargs['float_field_keys'] = []
        kwargs['str_field_keys']   = []
        
    batch = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        line = gen_line(**kwargs)
        batch.append(line)

    return(batch)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Generate a batch of Line Protocol points of a specified shape")
    parser.add_argument('measurement', type=str, default='cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--num_tags', type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument('--int_fields', type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument('--float_fields', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--str_fields', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--tag_key_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--tag_value_size', type=int, default=10)  
    parser.add_argument('--field_key_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--int_value_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--float_value_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--str_value_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--precision', type=str, choices = ['s','S','ms','MS','us','US','ns','NS'], default='s')
    parser.add_argument('--keep_keys_batch', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--keep_keys_session', action='store_true', help="")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # make a dictionary out of the parser args
    batch_args = vars(args)

    # add the other items to the dictionary
    if args.keep_keys_session:
        batch_args['tag_keys'] = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.num_tags)]
        batch_args['int_field_keys']   = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.int_fields)]
        batch_args['float_field_keys'] = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.float_fields)]
        batch_args['str_field_keys']   = [_gen_string(args.tag_key_size) for i in range(args.str_fields)]
        batch_args['keep_keys_batch']  = True
    else:
        batch_args['tag_keys'] = []
        batch_args['int_field_keys'] = []
        batch_args['float_field_keys'] = []
        batch_args['str_field_keys'] = []

    batch = gen_batch(**batch_args)

    for line in batch:
        print(line)
```

You can do the same type of transformation to get_line() and get_fieldset(). Beyond that, it might be cleaner to just extract the couple of args and pass them directly to the rest of the gen_xxx() functions rather than propagating kwargs everywhere.

Comment: I ended up doing just this!

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** to include Tomerikoo's suggestion to just use the args object instead of creating another object.

In thinking about this some more, it's nearly identical to use a class rather than a dictionary to store the arguments, but it makes the code a little easier to read IMHO. For example, `args.str_fields` is more intuitive than `kwargs.get('str_fields')`. And the easiest class to use (thanks @Tomerikoo ) is the object returned from `parse_args()`. So if it's not too late, here is an updated version using an object to store the arguments rather than a dictionary. Also, I used the `a = x if b else y` syntax to condense some of the assignment statements.

```
import argparse

def gen_batch(bargs):

    # Generate keys at batch level if `hold_keys` is True. 
    # This will keep Tag keys constant per line, reducing Series creation at database level.

    # Simplified...
    if not keep_keys_session:
        # these local variables are just to shorten the assignment lines
        tag_key_size = _gen_string(bargs.tag_key_size)
        keep = bargs.keep_keys_batch

        bargs.tag_keys         = [tag_key_size for i in range(bargs.num_tags)] if keep else []
        bargs.int_field_keys   = [tag_key_size for i in range(bargs.int_fields)] if keep else []
        bargs.float_field_keys = [tag_key_size for i in range(bargs.float_fields)] if keep else []
        bargs.str_field_keys   = [tag_key_size for i in range(bargs.str_fields)] if keep else []
        
    batch = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        line = gen_line(bargs)
        batch.append(line)

    return(batch)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Generate a batch of Line Protocol points of a specified shape")
    parser.add_argument('measurement', type=str, default='cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--num_tags', type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument('--int_fields', type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument('--float_fields', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--str_fields', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--tag_key_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--tag_value_size', type=int, default=10)  
    parser.add_argument('--field_key_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--int_value_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--float_value_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--str_value_size', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--precision', type=str, choices = ['s','S','ms','MS','us','US','ns','NS'], default='s')
    parser.add_argument('--keep_keys_batch', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--keep_keys_session', action='store_true', help="")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # add the other items
    tks = _gen_string(args.tag_key_size)
    args.tag_keys         = [tks for i in range(args.num_tags)] if args.keep_keys_session else []
    args.int_field_keys   = [tks for i in range(args.int_fields)] if args.keep_keys_session else []
    args.float_field_keys = [tks for i in range(args.float_fields)] if args.keep_keys_session else []
    args.str_field_keys   = [tks for i in range(args.str_fields)] if args.keep_keys_session else []
    args.keep_keys_batch  = True if args.keep_keys_session else False

    batch = gen_batch(args)

    for line in batch:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Why not just use `args`? It is already a simple container object holding some attributes, and all you do is copy its attributes to a new object... Just use `args` instead of `bargs`...

Comment: You are correct, there's no reason unless you need to add more customization to the container object, which was not a requirement from the OP. I guess that I was staring at it too long to see the obvious. I'll edit my answer to implement your suggestion.

Comment: I see you already edited what I was going to reply on your previous comment that you can add any attributes you want to the existing `args` object :)

Comment: I did :-). Mentally, I always isolate the args object from the rest of my code, usually pushing them into local variables, but I'll keep this model in mind moving forward where it makes sense.